# How to deploy modules with composer in a restricted environment

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I am starting a project with intranet hosting. Due to restrictions on outgoing traffic I cannot use an usual deployment strategy with composer like `git pull && composer.phar install` by referring to the `composer.lock` file. Though, adding an intranet remote repository and using something like `git push intranet master` is possible.

So far, I found two possibilities to manage this:

1. Do not add `.gitignore` to your `vendor/` path and commit everything in this folder with your project.
2. <del>Use `composer.phar archive` to generate a `.phar`-archive</del> (Misread documentation)

Since these solutions do not seem to be the recommended solutions for deployment, my question is: What are the major drawbacks and common problems for these solutions? How to avoid these problems?

Answer (score 0):

There are to many ways to deploy a laravel application to say which one is the way to go.

But have some points in mind:

- you might want to minify/concatenate your `css/sass/less/js` files first
- you surely want to upload your files

  - push from local to server
  - pull at server from a repository
- you might want to run `php artisan migrate` after each deploy on the server
- you might want to change some file permissions on the remote server after deploy

If you want a fully automated deployment you will need a good plan which tasks are needed for your project. It may differ on several projects.

There are many tools to make some of these steps easier and also many tutorials how to use them. Just to mention a few:

- [Laravel's remote component](http://blog.enge.me/post/laravel-41s-new-remote-component)
- [Rocketeer](http://rocketeer.autopergamene.eu/)
- [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/)
- [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)

If you just want to 'upload' your files to a remote server without further automation tasks you can use any synchronization tool like `rsync` or any ftp sync tool even winscp has a scripting engine to sync files to a remote server.

You see finding the right way to deploy is not easy and depends much on your environment and your project. Finally I would stand back from including `vendor/` in the git repo. This makes version control really ugly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I do not intend to use laravel, although it is a nice framework, but not the right one for my current project. Did not knew rocketeer, nice tool.

Comment: Oops this happens when you read to many laravel related questions :) Nevertheless you will have equivalent points whatever framework you use. Even if you write your application from scratch you might have to minify a script or have other tasks before/after deploying your files. Your deployment strategy will highly depend on the type of your project and your environment.

Comment: Everything you write is right, but only your last sentence answers my question for some degree. It is not my first deployment, the key difference is intranet hosting without access to the public net. But I can transfer a GIT Repo. Remote tool will not work.